# Openlayers with Bing's bird eye view

Tags: openlayers, bing-maps, bing

Has anyone been able to display Bing's bird view imagery set with Openlayers? There are examples that show how to use Openlayers with Bing, but it only works for 'Road', 'Aerial' and 'AerialWithLabels', but doesn't work with birdeye imagery sets. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing's Birds eye imagery can't be used outside of the Bing Maps control. This is a restriction in the terms of use. Note that the tile system for Birdseye imagery is completely different from OpenLayers and changes which each Birds eye scene, thus the reason why someone hasn't even bothered trying to put together a hack.